# Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors with --enable-mirrors=false

Tags: dart, flutter

.yaml file bellow:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  fluttertoast: ^2.0.9
  dio: ^1.0.6
  json_serializable: ^2.0.0
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  json_annotation: ^2.0.0
```

when I run:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
D/OpenGLRenderer( 5350): HWUI GL Pipeline
I/OpenGLRenderer( 5350): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer( 5350): Swap behavior 1
D/        ( 5350): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 
0xa12b3ec0, tid 5379
D/EGL_emulation( 5350): eglCreateContext: 0xa127cf60: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/        ( 5350): SurfaceInterface::setAsyncMode: set async mode 1
D/EGL_emulation( 5350): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa127cf60: ver 2 0 (tinfo         
0xa177fe80)
E/flutter ( 5350): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(188)] Dart Error: 
error: import of dart:mirrors with --enable-mirrors=false
E/flutter ( 5350): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/engine.cc(176)] Could not 
prepare to run the isolate.
E/flutter ( 5350): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/engine.cc(123)] Engine not prepare and launch isolate.
E/flutter ( 5350): 
[ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/android_shell_holder.cc(167)] Could not launch engine in configuration.
```

---

i know the problem is that 'json_serializable' but i didn't know how to resolve it. or is there any way to transform between model and json

Comment: Are you sure you don't have other dependencies in your `pubspec.yaml`?

Answer (score 3):

I did stumble across your post on my own search after solutions with your problem.

I assume that you want to use `json_serializable` for your own sourceCode creation.
If this is the case you should have 
`json_serializable: ^2.0.0`
under the `dev_dependencies`.

#### Explanation

`json_serializable` does use [dartlang/source_gen](https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen) internally. 
`source_gen` in turn does reference [`dart:mirrors`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html), which is not supported in flutter (as told in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/ZmX5gZHhU24)).

So long story in short: 
- through removing the dependency on `json_serializable` from your "build" dependencies you remove the dependency on mirrors which is stopping your flutterBuild.

---

> i know the problem is that 'json_serializable' but i didn't know how to resolve it. or is there any way to transform between model and json

I did not really got that part. 
At least for me this is not enough information to provide help on your modelgeneration.

Could try if you post a class in which you use `json_serializable` and the generated partial class.

Comment: i have solved it. i import 'package:json_serializable/json_serializable.dart'; delete it all is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I was using appengine plugin with MethodChannel and once I removed appengine dependency it all worked fine.