# Share objects between aqueduct and flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, aqueduct

I'm using aqueduct as a server where I defined an user object and extended it to make use of OAuth:

```
class ManagedUser extends ManagedObject<_User> implements _User, ManagedAuthResourceOwner<_User>
```

After finishing the work on aqueduct I started working on the flutter app and wanted to use the ManagedUser-object in flutter as well, that's why I thought about putting it into a separate project.

The problem I face now (during deployment) is the following:

```
ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors with --enable-mirrors=false
```

As I read here [Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors with --enable-mirrors=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000584/dart-error-error-import-of-dartmirrors-with-enable-mirrors-false) it's because flutter doesn't seem to support parts of aqueduct (which I unfortunately need in my shared project to use ManagedObject).

So I'm kinda stuck here. What are my options? I really don't like to map all objects again on the flutter side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to combine Aqueduct and Flutter in the same project - they have different compilation targets, and both take advantage of those targets.

The general approach is to use `aqueduct document` to create an OpenAPI document from your code, then use an OpenAPI code generator to build your client-side code. This approach is preferable to sharing code between the server and clients. Code can be shared between browser and mobile targets. It is a good idea to avoid having one type that represents the database, server and client definition of an object. A client type and a database table mapping will eventually have differences that will be difficult to manage.